# What do brackets mean after a type is specified when declaring variables in Stan?

Tags: stan, rstan, pystan

I saw a Stan program where the `data` block contained `int person[N_obs]`. Is this creating an array of integers of size `N_obs` that is called with `person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Brackets behind the variable names specify an array of the type that was specified before the name. In addition, for collection data types like `vector` and `matrix`, you need to specify the size behind the data type:

```
vector[N] y;
matrix[N, K] X;
```

You can also create arrays of collection data types.
For example

```
vector[N] X[K];
```

would specify an array of `K` vectors of size `N`.

Comment: The last code snippet's syntax is deprecated, I believe.  Now it's `array[K] vector[N] X;`

Comment: I think that's a new alternative way instead of a complete replacement, but you're right. Yours is more modern, I got stuck at pystan 2.19.

Comment: It's deprecated (and for some reason, Stan tends to remove deprecated features instead of letting them break) and scheduled for removal in an upcoming update https://mc-stan.org/docs/reference-manual/brackets-array-syntax.html

Comment: Good to know thanks! Looks like I'll have to bring myself up to date soon ;)